# Adding product image to ubercart checkout form

Tags: 8, ubercart

Has anyone able to get through altering/overriding the core cart checkout form? Any hooks that can help?

I am trying to add a product image to Ubercart /cart page ie. CartForm.

Comment: Have you tried with hook_form_alter?

Comment: Yes. I wrote checkout form but I need it on the cart form. Is there some setting that ubercart provides by default?